# Refresh a section of page while on mouse out. ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, onmouseover, onmouseout

How to refresh a section of page every 5 minutes while the mouse is not over that section in asp.net. Can I use update panel for this? and how can I do this?

Edit: Can I use javascript, I read something about running a asp method from javascript.. is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go the "UpdatePanel with Timer control" way, disabling the timer dynamically on the  client side is discussed [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1094798.aspx).

Comment: Yeah I think this is the answer. Thanks btw!

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way could be the UpdatePanel with a Timer control inside it to achieve just that.

If you have multiple UpdatePanels, learn about the UpdateMode-settings.

Comment: Yeah, I read something about timer and stuff and I think I can manage that, but how about the mouse over? it's a javascript stuff right? how can I integrate it with the timer so that it will be refreshed everytime mouse hover to the panel.

Comment: I'm sorry, do you want it to refresh every x seconds WHEN the mouse is hovering the panel, or when it is NOT hovering the panel?

That's JavaScript stuff, right. jQuery would be my choice.

Comment: I want to refresh the countdown when the mouse is hovering the panel. To indicate that the user is actively using the panel. Otherwise continue the countdown to refresh that page.